# Getting error for Data stage compare command line tool

Tags: data-warehouse, datastage, istool

I am using a utility provided in Data Stage 9.1 diffapicmdline.exe to compare two jobs from different environment. I am using following batch script code to read the job names from text file in loop:

```
    @echo off
SET var=

for /f "delims=" %%i in (grm_deploy.txt) do (C:\IBM\InformationServer91\Clients\Classic\diffapicmdline.exe /lhscd "/d=cs1cd:9080 /h=cs1i04 /u=user/p=password cs1cdhbi04/IST_GRM %%i" /rhscd "/d=cs1cd:9080 /h=cs1i04 /u=test /p=Pass cs1cdhbi04/TEST_NIMISH %%i" /t job /ot html /ol E:\compare_output.html)
echo this is the end
```

However I am getting following error:

```
D:\dataStage Components\Scripts>read_file.bat
Validating syntax of /lhscd.
Unknown flag specified 'jbLoadStgARxAR'
this is the end
```

Can anyone let me know what is going wrong over here?